# How can i count and not repeat the same letter in python

Tags: python, count, repeat

This code count the letters but i don't want it to rewrite the same letter twice. What can i do?

```
d=list('banttnay')
for letter in d:
    print letter, d.count(letter)
```

Output:

```
b 1
a 2
n 2
t 2
t 2
n 2
a 2
y 1
```

I don't want it to rewrite 'a 2' or 't 2' twice

Comment: Note that you don't need to make `banttnay` a list to be able to iterate (loop) over it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but only list has the `count` method required for getting the character count.

Comment: @phineas: `'abcc'.count('c')` -> `2`. Nope, strings have it too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you're right. It was a mistake to believe `list()` was there for a reason without testing the thesis immediately. Then, everything can be boiled down to `[(x, s.count(x)) for x in set(s)]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `set()`:

```
In [40]: d='banttnay'

In [41]: for x in set(d):
   ....:     print x,d.count(x)
   ....:     
a 2
y 1
b 1
t 2
n 2
```

or to maintain the order use [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)  from `collections` module:

```
In [67]: from collections import *

In [68]: c=OrderedDict()

In [69]: for x in d:
    c[x]=c.get(x,0)+1
In [71]: for x in c:
   ....:     print x,c[x]
   ....:     
b 1
a 2
n 2
t 2
y 1
```

or you can also use the `unique_everseen` recipe from the [`itertools Recipes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
>>> d='banttnay'
>>> from itertools import *
>>> def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
...     seen = set()
...     seen_add = seen.add
...     if key is None:
...         for element in ifilterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
...             seen_add(element)
...             yield element
...     else:
...         for element in iterable:
...             k = key(element)
...             if k not in seen:
...                 seen_add(k)
...                 yield element
... 
>>> for x in unique_everseen(d):
...     print x,d.count(x)
... 
b 1
a 2
n 2
t 2
y 1
```

Comment: Why do you declare `d` as a list?

Comment: @NiklasR removed that, just copied that from the question body.

Answer (score 3):

Use sets then - which allows only unique items in it:

```
d = 'banttnay'
for letter in set(d):
    print letter, d.count(letter)
```

Or use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to calculate amount of unique items in iterable:

```
   from collections import Counter
   cnt = Counter('banttnay')
   print cnt
```

And somethig like this:

```
word = 'banttnay'
res = dict(zip(set(word),map(word.count, word)))
```